# Como não mostrar elemento que não tem conteudo usando Angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Eu tenho que listar para o usuario uma mensagem dentro de um panel dependendo do "Radio" que cara vai clicar para mostrar uma mensagem. tem um radio como SIM e outro como NÃO.

se ele clicar no sim, vai ter que lhe mostrar uma mensagem e se for não para lhe mostrar nada. Eu consegui fazer, porém as vezes quando vc clica sim ele mostra o panel vazio.

Alguém tem uma ideia para me ajudar? aqui está o código com o que já consegui fazer:

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
  <div class="checkbox mt0 mb0 text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 pr-0">
        <label class="radio-inline c-radio mt0 text-bold color-green-template">
          <input type="radio" ng-model="pergunta.resposta" ng-value="true"/><span class="fa fa-circle assessment__checkbox"></span>{{'form.YES' | translate}}
        </label>
        <div class="pull-right hidden-xs hidden-sm">
          <div class="vertical-line-total color-green-template-light height-20 mt-5"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 pr-0">
        <label class="radio-inline c-radio mt0 text-bold color-green-template">
          <input type="radio" ng-model="pergunta.resposta" ng-value="false"/><span class="fa fa-circle assessment__checkbox"></span>{{'form.NO' | translate}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row border-error mt-10 br-md" ng-repeat="pergunta in $ctrl.security_questions  | orderBy: 'ordem_pergunta'" ng-if="pergunta.resposta">
  <p class="textMedium">{{item = pergunta.resposta_sim}}</p>
</div>
```

o que deve ser feito: é quando o usuario clicar em SIM e o LENGTH estiver menor que zero que ele não mostra nada.

Comment: Você não consegue dar um exemplo mínimo que reproduza o seu problema?

Comment: @Sorack valeu pela ajuda, mas consegui resolver a parada.

Answer (score 0):

Consegue resolver sozinho. era para fazer a seguinte:

```
<div class="row border-error mt-10 br-md" ng-repeat="pergunta in $ctrl.security_questions  | orderBy: 'ordem_pergunta'" ng-if="pergunta.resposta === true && pergunta.resposta_sim !== ''">
  <p class="textMedium">{{item = pergunta.resposta_sim}}</p>
</div>
```

{{item = pergunta.resposta_nao}}